# I have used Japanese characters in my code and works fine in Python, but when I run the exe file it doesnt display properly. Suggestions?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, exe, cjk

I have used Japanese characters in my code and works fine in Python, but when I run the exe file it doesnt display properly, it just displays as squares with question marks inside.

I used Auto Py to exe to convert the file.

I have had a look and I think it is to do with the encoding and I need to use UTF-8(?) but I have no idea how I could change this.

```
print("These characters are Japanese > こにちは")
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added a screen shot of my problem.

Comment: That's useful, but it isn't a [mcve].

Comment: sorry new to programming, I think this might be what you mean.

Comment: No need for much programming knowledge, just take a look at the page I linked.

Comment: yeah i checked it out and updated the main section

Comment: It could be that the font in your terminal does not support Japanese characters?

Comment: how could i check or change that?